# In Ruby, is there analog like "import ... as ..." in Python?

Tags: ruby, alias

In Python, I can import a subset of a module, give it a short name and reference only the short name from the code. e.g.

```
import bigmodule.bigobject.somethingbig as cutie
```

Is there something similar in ruby so I don't have to type the long string?

Comment: I don't think you can alias modules, if its really long and used in multiple places you could define a function that exposes that module or you could inject it in your initialize method and use as instance variables

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing(`import .. as ..`) in Ruby, Still you can make the method easily accessible via different methods.

Everything in ruby is an object which can be assigned to another variable just like any other object. You can just assign the submodule to a variable and the variable can be treated like the submodule reference.

```
# Assume you have followed the rails conventions for naming and file structure
# 'bigmodule/bigobject/somethingbig'
cutie = Bigmodule::Bigobject::Something

# Now you can access module methods with `cutie` reference variable.
# You can also define a method, which access the submodule
def cutie
  Bigmodule::Bigobject::Something
end
```

Example:

```
# Assigning String class to a variable
a = String
a.new("Hello World") # It will produce a new string with value as 'Hello World'
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. If you are going from python to Ruby it is one of those things you'll get used to. You will learn that it really doesn't make sense to do it the python way.

But do you have an example of some code that you don't like as a result of this? There may be a better way.